# Auth.signIn() using Device - AWS Amplify with React-Native

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I would like my react-native app to sign in automatically with the Device Remember option from cognito, but I didn't find an option in the Auth.signIn() method to pass the device instead the username and logon. Is there a better way of doing that?

Answer (score -1):

It has method called `currentAuthenticatedUser`

```
Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(() => {
    // User is logged in
}).catch(() => {
    // User is not logged in
})
```

Comment: Thank you Ravi - do you mean when the device is a known one it would authenticate automatically? I was guessing I would need to do something on code level to check that...

Comment: If you are calling Auth.signin() on device with required user details, you can get it via this method untill you call logout/signout.

Comment: Ok but actually what I want is, every time the user opens the App, it keeps logged, or login automatically based on the device information, without the user have to type credentials again. He would do that only the 1st time.

Comment: That is what signin command does, but as a developer you have to do something to check whether user is logged in or not. `currentAuthenticatedUser()` is there to check that thing only, you just need to redirect user based on it's output.